# oh-my-zsh: plugin 'git-remote-branch' not found

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

When starting [oh-my-zsh] a message shows up since a few weeks saying

```
[oh-my-zsh] plugin 'git-remote-branch' not found
```

How do I get this error message away? I do not care about the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

The repository at https://github.com/webmat/git_remote_branch
says this plugin is no longer maintained.

You can remove the error message on shell in the zsh config file as follows:

Execute on terminal:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Find line containing the plugin:

```
plugins=(... git-remote-branch ...)
```

Remove

```
git-remote-branch
```

from that line.

Then restart the terminal.

Now the error should be gone.

Comment: I have the same error but I don't have any "git-remote-branch" in my zshrc plugins .-.

Comment: The fact that the repository isn't mantained it doesn't mean it does not work. The error message zsh is telling you is because it can not find the plugin folder within the ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins folder, removing the line plugin reference in the ~/.zshrc file you're suppressing the error, not solving it.

Comment: @Sebastian: The question was how to get rid of the error message, not how to get the plugin working.

Comment: @Sebastian: I changed that part to make it more clear. I didn't care about the plugin.